# link in cgridview is not displaying correctly

Tags: yii

It appears that the links aren't in correct order and I can't figure out why. I have it in other grids, they seem to be fine.

This is what the link shows:

- index.php?ajax=gridID&id=180&r=controller/action

when it's suppose to show:

- index.php?r=controller/action&id=180

this is my value in gridview:

```
'value'=>function($data,$row){
    if (intval($data->sid) ==$someID){
        if($data->accept == "ACCEPTED")
            return CHtml::Link("[X]",  array("controller/action","id"=>$data->id),
            array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?',
            'class'=>'stat')
    );
}
```

where grid is suppose to refresh on confirm:

```
<?php 
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('stat', "
    $('#gridId a.stat').live('click', function() {
            $.fn.yiiGridView.update('gridId', {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    success: function() {
                    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('gridId');

                    }
            });
            return false;
    });"
);
?>
```

Comment: looks fine, the question is CHtml::Link generate this link or $.fn.yiiGridView

Comment: what is wrong with this url?

Comment: hmm, when i move CHTML::link before the first if statement, it shows the link properly.

Answer (score 0):

if you need generate url on "path" format (controller/action/id/180) and without script name you can set urlFormat property in UrlManager to "path" and set showScriptName property to false. Look [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager) and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#showScriptName-detail)

in aplication config file:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,  
 )
```

Comment: i dont think it's the urlmanager problem. The url keeps showing ajax when all i have is a normal link.